# Can someone tell me what what these question marks in my navigator window mean? (Xcode 4.2)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I duplicated some classes and xib's and they all have this "?" next to their names:

[image: View of navigator window]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are files that are not being tracked by your version control system. If you right-click them, there should be a **Source Control** sub-menu with the option to **Add** the files.

Answer (score 4):

It means those files are not under source control.

Read this doc for more info: [Xcode 4 User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html)

[image: Source Control Status]

Answer (score 1):

Their source-control status is unknown.  Most likely, you've created the files but not added them to the repository.